# How to get domain from a NSURLAuthenticationChallenge instance

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, nsurlsession, self-signed

The **self-signed certificate** of https is used in my project. The following methods will be triggered during the request.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
```

How do I get valid information about the certificate from`NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`, at least I need to get the **domain name** in the certificate.
First of all, the client does not store any local certificates; in the process I found that the `challenge.protectionSpace.host` gets the requested host instead of the domain name in the certificate.
Hope to get an answer. Thank you!

Comment: using OpenSSL would be a straightforward way to read the certificate.